# Is there any built in function to get the list of nodes (point node) within a certain diameter range in anylogic?

Tags: anylogic, agent-based-modeling

When a person agent is absorbing one node, I am trying to find the **list/array** of other **nodes** (point node) around him **within a certain diameter range** (let's say 10feet). Is there any built-in function to sort those nodes around the agent? I was trying "**agentInRange", "getNearestAgent"** but those aren't actually the right ones for my need as these functions return a list of person agent within the range not the list of nodes around him. How I can get the list of nodes (point node) around an agent? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Not that I know of.

But you can easily put all nodes in your model into a collection, then let your agents loop across that collection to check. Something like this, will need to be adjusted to your needs and conditions

```
for (PointNode currentNode : col_AllNodes) {
    if (currentNode.getX() ...) { // check your condition
        return true;
    }
}
```

You can easily put all nodes into a collection by selecting them all, right-click and then  selected "create collection" as below:
[image]

Comment: Thanks, Ben! this is one good idea which I already tried. Ideally, it should work fine but for some weird reason, some nodes are missing. I think I have some glitch in my code, which I am trying to find out. However, thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: well, make sure all nodes are in that collection. And put in some tracelns to check in detail what "is missing" :)